# PHP: need some clarification about custom error and exception handlers and trigger_error

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

Question #1:
I have a custom error_handler to be registered by `set_error_handler()`. If I intercept `E_USER_ERROR` inside it should I call `die()` or `exit()` manually to end the script or it will be done automatically by PHP.

Question #2:
I have a custom exception_handler to be registered by `set_exception_handler()`. Should I call `die()` or `exit()` manually to end the script or it will be done automatically by PHP.

Question #3:
If i have `error_reporting(0)` does it mean that my `trigger_error()` calls will not trigger errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the manual? :)

1.) http://php.net/set-error-handler

> Also note that it is your responsibility to die() if necessary. If the error-handler function returns, script execution will continue with the next statement after the one that caused an error.

2.) http://php.net/set-exception-handler

> Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

3.) http://php.net/trigger-error

> Generates a user-level error/warning/notice message.

This will obey your `error_reporting` setting for `E_USER_NOTICE`'s unless a second parameter is used.

Comment: Big thanx! About #1 and #2 all is clear. About #3. So if my error reporting is set to 0 no `E_USER_ERROR`s will be triggered?

Comment: Correct. All you're doing is creating the error manually (a notice by default). It still obeys the [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) level, which for `0` would be to disable all error reporting.

Comment: Great! It is always better to ask EGG than digesting PHP docu!!